# Boot partition is not created properly on SD card for pandabaord

Tags: android, cross-compiling, porting, android-sdcard, pandaboard

I want to do android Kitkat Porting on Pandabaord. AOSP code is compiled successfully and boot ,system ,user data,u-boot and MLO all the image files are generated after compilation now I want to make a boot-able SD card for Panda board and I used below script for it.

```
#!/bin/sh 
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
echo "example usage: $0 /dev/sdc \$ANDROID_ROOT"
exit 1
fi

DRIVE=$1
ANDROID_ROOT_DIR=$2

sudo umount ${DRIVE}*

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$DRIVE bs=1 count=1024
sudo sync
sudo parted $DRIVE mklabel gpt
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart boot fat32 1MB 9MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart system ext4 9MB 521MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart cache ext4 521MB 1033MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart userdata ext4 1033MB 2033MB
sudo parted $DRIVE mkpart media fat32 2033MB 3033MB
sudo sync

sudo mkfs.ext4 ${DRIVE}2 -L system
sudo mkfs.ext4 ${DRIVE}3 -L cache
sudo mkfs.ext4 ${DRIVE}4 -L userdata
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 ${DRIVE}5 -n media
sudo sync

sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/device/ti/panda/xloader.bin of=$DRIVE bs=131072 seek=1
sudo sync
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/device/ti/panda/bootloader.bin of=$DRIVE bs=262144 seek=1
sudo sync
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/boot.img of=${DRIVE}1
sudo sync
${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.img ${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.ext4.img
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/out/target/product/panda/system.ext4.img of=${DRIVE}2
sudo sync
sudo e2label ${DRIVE}2 system
sudo sync
```

After running above script this code parted DRIVE as 5 partition as system, cache, user data and media. But why does boot not created? that is, {DRIVE}1 is not set know? Then where will be xloader.bin, bootloader.bin and boot.img all stored?

Thanks for Help in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

ROM Code of the pandaboard looks for a "bootloader" code in two places, depending on option which you want to use:

- Raw mode - then image has to be in one of following location: 0KB, 128KB, 256KB, 384KB on SdCARD and image contains special header which ROM checks.
- Boot from an active primary partition (file has to be called MLO) Fat12/16/32.

it looks like that you are going to use raw mode, so xloader.bin (MLO) contains things to boot up your board (offset 128KB). The code is read to memory by ROM Code of pandaboard 
and then probably loads next stage of bootloder- bootloader.bin

So what you are doing here:

```
sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/device/ti/panda/xloader.bin of=$DRIVE bs=131072 seek=1

sudo dd if=${ANDROID_ROOT_DIR}/device/ti/panda/bootloader.bin of=$DRIVE bs=262144 seek=1
```

is just coping two files to SDCARD offsets 128KB and 256KB respectively, and these images are stored there.